# How to build user defined reports using django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a project that needs several reports.  Problem is, I don't know what those reports should be, and I'd like to let the user create them on the fly (and then save them).  In going over how to do this, the thing that keeps hitting me in the shins is that templates are written using dotted notation so there is no easy way to say

```
{% for field in fields %}
    <td>{{ object.field }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

So, I've thought up some ideas, basically to have a template generator, that just renders the template to a string, and renders the page from that.

```
from django.template import Template
t = Template(report_defintion.create())
t.render(context)
```

Another method is to use a template-tag that takes the list of fields and renders each "row" in the report that way.

```
{% render_row object fields %}
```

Those are the two best ideas I've come up with so far.  Is there a better way to do this?  Is there a django app out there that already does it?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider leveraging the [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/) functionality and if you know in advance what parts of a model will appear in a particular report the only question then is what "view" of the `Model` you want to generate.  The end user can then specify the instance objects (from one or more models) that they are interested in and the ordering of those objects.  You then build the final report from these components.

One of the shortcomings of Django (although someone please correct me if I'm wrong about this) is that form object rendering is always in the context of an editable form, even though often it would be very nice to have a "read-only" view of the form.  Where this has been an issue for me I've simply implemented a "renderer" on the `Model` class itself (this is not very Django-esque, but it better fits my ideas of OOD and encapsulation).  Typically I create `as_row()` and `as_rotable()` methods on my `Model` which self render to HTML in either a "one instance per row" or "one field per row and one instance per table" format.

[Generic Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/) should help with this, but I haven't quite figured out how to make this work smoothly, so for the moment I'm left with something like the example below.

url.py:

```
from gridportal.wsmr.views                  import list, create, view, edit, copy, delete, reset
...
url(r'task/(?P<id>\d+)/?$', view, {'tmpl': 'wsmr/wsmrtask_detail.html'}, name="task_view"), 
...
```

views.py:

```
from gridportal.wsmr.forms          import WSMRTaskViewForm
...
def view(request, id, tmpl):
    task = get_object_or_404(WSMRTask, pk=id)
    form = WSMRTaskViewForm(instance=task)
    return render_to_response(tmpl, {'object': form,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py:

```
class WSMRTaskViewForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = WSMRTask
```

wsmr/wsmrtask_detail.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<table>
    {{ object.instance.as_rotable|safe }}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

models.py:

```
class WSMRTask(GridTask):
    ...
    def as_row(self):
        return GridTask.as_row(self) + """
<td> <a href=%s/%s>%s</a> </td>
<td> %s </td>
<td> %s </td>
        """ % (self.task_url, basename(self.mtz.name), basename(self.mtz.name), self.resolution, self.solvent)

    def as_rotable(self):
        return GridTask.as_rotable(self) + """
<tr><td>MTZ</td><td> <a href=%s/%s>%s</a> </td></tr>
<tr><td>resolution (A) </td><td> %s </td></tr>
<tr><td>solvent</td><td> %s </td></tr>
        """ % (self.task_url, basename(self.mtz.name), basename(self.mtz.name), self.resolution, self.solvent)
```